# Kolmogorov complexity is uncomputable using reductions

Tags: complexity-theory, computation-theory, reduction, decidable

Can anyone please give me a proof of K-Complexity is unsolvable using reductions.

> eg:
>
> PCP(2) <= PCP(3)

I can prove that PCP(3) is unsolvable by reducing to PCP(2) (by mapping every instance).

I am not sure how to reduce K-Complexity to another known undecidable problem (like halting problem). i.e., *X* <= K-Complexity

Can you please provide me proof for that? At least provide me some idea (*X* ).

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This question would find willing and able answerers over at [TCS.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is best suited for `cstheory.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: Thank you.. will wait for sometime and post the question at SE.

Comment: By K-complexity do you mean the set of non-Random numbers? Because this is a r.e. but simple set, hence not complete, and there is no reduction from a complete problem to it.

Comment: @AndreaAsperti  I really don't understand what you are asking.  But this question is answered here-  [link] (http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31278/proof-for-kolmogorov-complexity-is-uncomputable-using-reductions/31305?noredirect=1#comment71359_31305)

Comment: Yes, precisely, you can find a couple of proofs in Odifreddi's book "Classical Recursion Theory", Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics, vol 125.